# App rejection due to old non compliant aabs in CLOSED TRACK. Cant deactivate them. Release not automatically deactivating them

Tags: android, release, google-play-console

My app was rejected due to old aabs being non-compliant v 127 and v 128.

It was Flurry lib causing issues - which I fixed.

I had this issue at the start of the years so I was told it was probably an old aab in a testing track.

And to release the latest version to all track to deactivate previous versions.

In August I did this and version 129 was successfully released with compliant Flurry.

We dont release mobile apps often so it wasn't until this week NOV we had to release v 130.

I released to PROD track.

As I was submitting to  testing track OPEN, CLOSED and INTERNAL I suddenly got the non compliant email for 127 and 128 again.

I thought it was because I had pushed PRODD first.
So I did a new release 131 to TESTING first then prod.
But same rejection email for 127 and 128.

After hunting around it appears 127 and 128 are still active.

I know you used to be able to manually deactivate them but not longer.

The successful release 129 should have deactivated at least 128 but didn't.
It was published to all tracks and successfully released.

I appealed the rejection this week and support just sent me back the same  automated email with bits highlighted. Which are missing steps - so they and their email were useless.

It says :

Click Manage track > Create new release
If the release with the violating app bundles / APKs are in a draft state, discard the release.
Otherwise, add the policy compliant version of app bundles / APKs.
Make sure the noncompliant version is under the "Not Included" section of this release.
Enter a release name and click Save. Once saved, click Review release, then proceed to roll out the release to 100%.

They said "Make sure the noncompliant version is under the "Not Included" section of this release." but when I create the release on the closed track I cant see any "Not Included section to remove 127 and 128"
The only aab listed is the latest.

Where is the NOT INCLUDED section.
I only created a new release in the CLOSED TRACK.

Comment: If possible, try using the latest compliant version on the problematic track. I too had this issue sometime ago.

Comment: yes i  had the issue too and used the latest compliant on all tracks after this. now up to 131 and its suddenly complaining about 127 and 128. 127 is in two CLOSING TRACK so may be the issue and 127 and 128 may have not been fully published. Issue now is how to deactivate them or their tracks. You can only pause tracks. its a complete pain and google Play support are useless.

Comment: Once `131` is published on relevant tracks, you can *pause* them. There’s no deactivating though, only pausing.

Comment: ok solved it. the line in the instruction "Click Manage track > Create new release" should be rewritten as "Click Manage track" then INSIDE the track click the button called Create new release". I thought 'Create new release' was a general instruction so I was creating new CLOSED TRACK for each new release. 
And later the non conforming aab was in an old track. 
The hideously FLAT and WHITE all over UI of Google Play Console DOES NOT HELP!!